# How to do 64bit Integer arithmetic in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Anyone have any suggestions on how to perform arithmetic on 64bit integers in Node.js?  The node-int64 package doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: I think you'll find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/javascript-cant-handle-64-bit-integers-can-it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Javascript does not support 64 bit integers, because the native number type is a 64-bit double, giving only 53 bits of integer range.

You can create arrays of 32-bit numbers (i.e. `Uint32Array`) but if there were a 64-bit version of those there'd be no way to copy values from it into standalone variables.

There are some modules around to provide 64bit integer support:

- [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint)
- [bignum (based on OpenSSL)](https://github.com/justmoon/node-bignum)
- [int64](https://github.com/broofa/node-int64)

Maybe your problem can be solved using one of those libraries.

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason, that one didn't come up in my googling.

Answer (score 6):

As of v10.4.0 NodeJS supports the BigInt type natively (see [MDN BigInt docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)). These support arithmetic operations too.