# KnexJS with postgreSQL returns all data as string, does not respect the data type that comes from the database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, knex.js

I have a problem in KnexJs I'm using with postgreSQL, but every time I make a select the knex answers all the data in the table as a string, which is not the case, since there are fields that are numbers and the knex Pass me like string someone would know how to help me I'm desperate.

Select knex

```
function getDeadlines(){
    let query = knex(prazo.getTableName())
                    .select(prazo.properties.idDeadline.getDbProperty(), prazo.properties.deadline.getDbProperty())
                    .orderBy(prazo.properties.deadline.getDbProperty(), 'desc')
    return query
}
```

Response knexjs code

```
{
    deadlines: [
      {
        cd_prazo_pk_36: "1", //(Is a numeric in database table)
        ds_prazo_36: "A Vista"
      },
      {
        cd_prazo_pk_36: "2",  //(Is a numeric in database table)
        ds_prazo_36: "7 Dias"
      },
      {
        cd_prazo_pk_36: "4", //(Is a numeric in database table)
        ds_prazo_36: "21 Dias"
      },
      {
        cd_prazo_pk_36: "3", //(Is a numeric in database table)
        ds_prazo_36: "14 Dias"
      }
   ]
}
```

cd_prazo_pk_36 it's not a string, it's a numeric

Connection

```
    development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host : 'localhost',
      user : 'postgres',
      password : '123',
      database : 'testing',
      charset: 'utf8'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
  },
```

I already thank you

Comment: Does your underlying Postgres table definition actually define the columns you expect to be numbers as a numeric type?  You might want to include the relevant Knex code in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [knex postgres returns strings for numeric/decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569216/knex-postgres-returns-strings-for-numeric-decimal-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> node-postgres will convert a database type to a JavaScript string if it doesn't have a registered type parser for the database type. Furthermore, you can send any type to the PostgreSQL server as a string and node-postgres will pass it through without modifying it in any way.

https://node-postgres.com/features/types

Knex uses node-postgres database driver for accessing postgresql.

You can use https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types to override default parsers for each datatype.

Comment: I do not quite understand how to use node-postgres types with the knexjs, could you explain me better?

Comment: Thanks friend, i got it .