# Retrieve records of objects with the correct types

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql

I have the following Typescript function that query a table in Postgresql;I pass a generic type and I expect to have an array of objects of the same type passed as input, but it doesn't:

```
export async function pgQuery<T>(
  query: string,
  postgreSqlClient: Client = postgreSqlClientGlobal
) {
  const log = extendLogger(_log, pgQuery);
  try {
    const res = await postgreSqlClient.query<T>(query);
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    log.error({ error }, `PostgreSql query ERROR`);
    throw new Error(`PostgreSql query ERROR - ${error}`);
  }
}
```

The input type T is:

```
{country: string,
 age_min: number,
 age_max: number}
```

And in the table of the Postgresql DB I have records like this:

```
{
  loc_name: "Albania",
  age_min: 15,
  age_max: 64
}
```

but I have, as output of the executed query, object like this:

```
{country: string,
 age_min: string,
 age_max: string}
```

Example:

```
{
  loc_name: "Albania",
  age_min: "15",
  age_max: "64"
}
```

How to retrieve the correct types?
pg stands for: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `postgreSqlClient.query<T>(query)` is implemented.

When you interact with an external database, just typing the request as type `T` is not enough to guarantee that you will actually get a value of type `T`.

When you declare the type as `T`, Typescript will just trust you and assume that the type is `T`. However, since you are fetching an external resource, you cannot be sure at runtime that the value is actually of type `T`.

If you want to be 100% sure, you must implement some sort of runtime validation. Libraries like [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) and [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) are made for this purpose.

Comment: I'm using Runtypes to validate external data and in fact, passing the type as T and checking the returned type object fails; also, I'm sure external records are of this type, but i still get strings as output.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution (I'm writing a "disposable code"...) is to cast the fields in the postgresql query (es.: select loc_name, age_min::int, age_max::int from table;); for more info see:
[pg-promise returns integers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168501/pg-promise-returns-integers-as-strings)