# JavaScript's equality operator giving incorrect result?

Tags: javascript, equality

```
9007199254740992 == 9007199254740991
false

9007199254740992 == 9007199254740992 
true

9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993
true  //  whats going on ?

9007199254740992 == 9007199254740994
false

9007199254740992 == 9007199254740995
false
```

Could someone explain the logic behind the 3rd check? Why does it return TRUE?

Comment: Javascript stores numbers as [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). You can't [safely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) represent `9007199254740993` as an integer. Given your choice of integer (`9007199254740991 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) something tells me you already know this?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but 9007199254740993 becomes 9007199254740992 when entered in the console of my browser. That would explain why you are seeing it being equal to 9007199254740992.

Comment: @RGraham sounds like you should put that as the answer

Comment: @forgivenson It's been asked hundreds of times before. I'm trying to find an appropriate duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Javascript stores numbers as 64-bit floating-point numbers. These can only represent integers up to [53 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643650/238978) exactly, and after that they are only approximate. The largest exact integer in JS is therefore [9 007 199 254 740 991](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/238978).