# Stop Sublime/Node.js shortening numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I work with big numbers Sublime Text 2 or Node.js (I don't know which one it actually does) shortens those big numers. For example:

var example = Math.pow(2, 70);

example = 1.1805916207174113e+21

I would like to see the full number (1180591620717411303424), but I don't know which settings I have to change for that nor do I know where to find those settings.

Comment: what means full number? `1180591620717411303424`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's NodeJS that's "shortenting" these numbers. It display large numbers in scientific notation, because Javascript uses 64-bit floating point numbers.

If you're referring to displaying numbers not in scientific notation, i.e. 'x.xxxxxxxxxxe+yy', refer to this SO answer:

[How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)

If you're looking to handle numbers larger than 64-bit floats...

[JavaScript can't handle 64-bit integers, can it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/javascript-cant-handle-64-bit-integers-can-it)

And note the mention of the library "BigNumber".