# Working with 64 bit timestamps in node.js

Tags: node.js, datetime

My C++/cli server sends to node.js TCP client a 64 bit integer representing a date(according to [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)). How to interpret the value in node Buffer as a javascript DateTime instance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html ? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because your question is a little vague (with regards to what you have done and what you're having problems with)

Comment: @CodyG. I've read this, but there is no methods to work with 64 bit values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/does-javascript-support-64-bit-integers