# How to call a NEAR smart contract from js with a U64 argument?

Tags: javascript, integer, nearprotocol

I'm working with NEAR's canonical [example](https://github.com/near-examples/NFT/blob/master/contracts/rust/src/lib.rs) of an NFT smart contract, which implements the NEP4 standard API for NFT tokens.

Half of those API calls require a 64-bit integer for the token_id argument.

I'd like to call this API from a web app. But those u64 values can't be normal Javascript numbers on the client side, because [Javascript integers are only 53 bits wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/does-javascript-support-64-bit-integers)

[This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378144/why-cant-i-read-this-hashmap-in-a-near-contract/64438703#64438703) can work for some cases, but it requires changing the API signature. I think that breaks compatibility with the standard.

I've tried passing the value as a string, and as a BigInt.  But I got errors in both cases.

How can I call NEAR contract methods from Javascript if they require 64-bit values?  For instance, can I trick the JSON serializer to turn a BigInt on the client into a u64 on the wire?

Comment: Yes, as noted by Matt Lockyear: this was a question about the old, deprecated standard.  NEP-171 solved this problem.  Use that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right this is a bug and should be fixed by fixing the signature to accept `TokenId` as a `String` and then parse it into `u64`. I filed an issue: https://github.com/near-examples/NFT/issues/117

Comment: Why not have Rust SDK deserialize u64 from string? It's not possible to have 64-bit integer in JSON.

Comment: Or have the serializer in the Rust JS API turn some client type like BigInt into a JSON integer when it creates the JSON call?

Answer (score 2):

This is the latest NFT standard. The one you are referencing is deprecated. Apologies for not answering the question, but I think it's important to point this out.

https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/README.html

Reference implementation here:
https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/tree/standards/nft/near-contract-standards/src/non_fungible_token

You can see another implementation of this standard here along with a marketplace here:
https://github.com/near-apps/nft-market

Comment: could you detail your answer a little bit more please ?