# REST requests json Long different from original Long

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I am using Java 16 and spring-boot (2.5.3) to create a REST api which returns a Long property and also the String version of the Long property.
The Long is created via Javas `Random().nextLong()` and the String via `toString()` of that Long value.
In the return object I set the Long to prop1 and the String to prop2.
If I debug my code both values inside the return object are the same.
If I look at my response inside the browsers devtools both sometimes are different.

Example: prop2: "8809294616433182964", prop1: 8809294616433183000

Can someone explain the reason for this and how to use a Long without this happening?
If I use `Long.valueOf(Random().nextInt())` everything works fine, so it somehow dependents on the size of the long value.

All my objects ids are Long based and I don't want to have a problem with this if the ids get too big.

Comment: If everything is setup as you described, then both values should be the same. Could you please share Your code (a minimal reproducing example, at best)? Did you try to set `Long.MAX_VALUE`? What does Your response look like in that case?

Comment: JavaScript does not support 64-bit integers out-of-the-box, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643626/does-javascript-support-64-bit-integers).

Comment: @slauth so the json parser of spring (jackson) already uses the js 53-bit integer and approximates the value like in your linked question described?

Comment: I would have thought that the json which is generated on java side should still be correct and only inside the js code the value would be wrong.

Comment: @chaosKP you are right, the error only occurrs when *parsing* the JSON. Most likely your browser's devtools console is doing that. Better try with `curl` when in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @slauth said, problem is the js 53 bit integer implementation.