# WinJS OData JSON

Tags: odata, winjs

try to send data to my database by web service an get this error:

```
Primitive values of type 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Int64' must be quoted in the payload. Make sure the value is quoted
```

here is my code:

```
var newEntry = {
        datum: entryDate,
        monat: parseFloat(entryMonth),
        taetigkeit: document.getElementById("addWork").value,
        total: parseFloat(document.getElementById("addTotal").value),
        totalV: parseFloat(document.getElementById("addTotalV").value),
        in_auswertung: 0,
        teil_projekt_id: parseFloat(document.getElementById("addSubProject").value),
        projekt_id: parseFloat(document.getElementById("addProject").value),
        TimeStamp: entryDate,
        sAuftraggeber: document.getElementById("addContractor").value,
        iidBenutzer: parseFloat(298),//sessionStorage.getItem("userId"),
        akt_id: parseFloat(document.getElementById("addActivity").value)
    };

    WinJS.xhr({
        type: "post",
        url: requestUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(newEntry),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        }

    }).then(
          function complete(response) {

          },
```

Thanks
Marlowe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one of your properties has a declared type of `Edm.Decimal` or `Edm.Int64`. These values must be serialized as a string (i.e., the number wrapped in `"` characters) in OData's JSON format. If you're not sure what the declared types of the properties are, you can look up the entity type in the server's `$metadata` document (typically available at `http://.../MyService.svc/$metadata`).

So, for the property or properties that are `Edm.Int64` or `Edm.Decimal`, you could remove the call to `parseFloat()` and just keep it as a string.

Comment: Immediately below the up and down arrows (at the top left of the answer), there's an outline of a checkmark. You can click that to accept an answer. For a general intro to stackoverflow, you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/about