# Difference between odatamediatypeformatter and jsonmediatypeformatter

Tags: json.net, odata

I would like to understand the difference between **OdataMediaTypeFormatter** and **JsonMediaTypeFormatter**. I tried searching the web but didn't get an answer to this. In my product we discovered recently that *OdataMediaTypeFormatter* was being used while we were assuming that we are using *JsonMediaTypeFormatter*. Our clients use json.net to serialize their objects, so I would like to switch to using *JsonMediaTypeFormatter* but want to know what will change with this switch.

I know one difference between the two - one with respect to deserializing 'long' datatype. odata's json requires long values to be quoted while json.net doesn't. As mentioned in this thread here - [WinJS OData JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544469/winjs-odata-json)

Any pointers on this will help. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` sits both in the namespace `System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter` (a.k.a the ASP.NET Web API for OData V1-3) and `System.Web.OData.Formatter` (a.k.a the ASP.NET Web API for OData V4). So it is a media type formatter for OData payload types (namely Atom and JSON light and JSON verbose for OData V3 and OData JSON for OData V4).

On the other hand, `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` belongs to `System.Net.Http.Formatting`. So it is a native part of the .NET framework for JSON payload handling. They all derive from `System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter` but they have their own implementations of serializing and deserializing the different payload kinds they are targetting respectively.

To underestand what is OData JSON, you can refer to this link [OData JSON Format Version 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html). From it you can see the `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` also deals with a lot of OData specific JSON elements and attributes, which `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` has no knowledge of.

Thus, for your scenario, since you're using this generic JSON serializer: JSON.NET to serialize objects, there should be nothing negative about switching to using `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` as long as your client is not talking to an OData service.